# Mocking a class that inherits from another class

Tags: c#, testing, refactoring

So here is the scenario, I am refactoring some spaghetti code. My first problem was a chain of classes that newed up other classes, I fixed this by making the ctor of the class I want to test (Search.cs) take the class it needs as a dependency, it looks like this now.

```
 public Search(XmlAccess xmlFile, SearchDatabaseConnect searchDatabaseConnection)
    {
        this.xmlFile = xmlFile;
        FsdcConnection = searchDatabaseConnection;
        Clear();
    }
```

I'm newing it up further up the chain. That is all good but I have a little problem.

The class that I am ctor injecting inherits from another class, I have Resharper and I have extracted interfaces but the problem is the dependency class inherits from another concrete class - see what I mean?

```
 public class SearchDatabaseConnect : DatabaseConnect, ISearchDatabaseConnect 
{ // }
```

I don't know what to do about the inheritance on DatabaseConnect? How do I mock that? Obviously if that wasn't there I would be all set I could mock an ISearchDatabaseConnect and away we go but I am stuck on the inheritance of a concrete class. I am sure people have run into this before my googl'ing was a failure when it came to finding examples about this.

Thanks in advance for any useful suggestions.

Comment: Just for reference "newing it up" is generally called instantiating ;-)

Comment: yes, thank you - it's simply a matter of personal preference, I tend to like the term "newing" cause it a) is the keyword the code uses (well OK new is) and b) somehow seems more fun that the term instantiating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `DatabaseConnect` also have an interface extracted from it?  I think you should be able to set it up like:

```
public interface IDatabaseConnect

public class DatabaseConnect : IDatabaseConnect

public interface ISearchDatabaseConnect : IDatabaseConnect

public class SearchDatabaseConnect : DatabaseConnect, ISearchDatabaseConnect
```

And now making a `Mock<ISearchDatabaseConnect>` will get all the "stuff" from both interfaces.

---

Side-note, your method/constructor there should probably take in the interface, not the concrete:

```
public Search(XmlAccess xmlFile, ISearchDatabaseConnect searchDatabaseConnection) { ... }
```

That way you can inject the mock, like:

```
var mockedSearchDatabaseConnect = new Mock<ISearchDatabaseConnect>();
var search = new Search(xmlFile, mockedSearchDatabaseConnect.Object);
```